# POSTGRES: How to do loop & How to join inside the loops?

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL Newbie here.

I have two tables like these

Table: Order

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
 ID serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 data json NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO orders (data)
VALUES
 (
 '{"customer":"John Doe","items":[{"1234":{"attributes":{"name":"parent"}},"id":"1234","isPhone":true,"items":[{"5678":{"attributes":{"name":"child"}},"id":"5678","isPhone":false}]},{"9012":{"attributes":{"name":"parent"}},"id":"9012","isPhone":true,"items":[{"3456":{"attributes":{"name":"child"}},"id":"3456","isPhone":false}]}]}'
 );

 INSERT INTO orders (data)
VALUES
 (
 '{"customer":"John Doe","items":[{"7890":{"attributes":{"name":"parent"}},"id":"7890","isPhone":true,"items":[{"0987":{"attributes":{"name":"child"}},"id":"0987","isPhone":false}]},{"6543":{"attributes":{"name":"parent"}},"id":"6543","isPhone":true,"items":[{"2109":{"attributes":{"name":"child"}},"id":"2109","isPhone":false}]}]}'
 );
```

Table: Backlog

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE backlog (
 ID serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 data json NOT NULL
);

  INSERT INTO backlog (data)
VALUES
 ('{"id":"5678","isAvailable":true,"order_id":1}'),
 ('{"id":"9012","isAvailable":true,"order_id":1}'),
 ('{"id":"3456","isAvailable":false,"order_id":1}'),
 ('{"id":"7890","isAvailable":false,"order_id":2}'),
 ('{"id":"0987","isAvailable":false,"order_id":2}'),
 ('{"id":"6543","isAvailable":false,"order_id":2}'),
 ('{"id":"2109","isAvailable":false,"order_id":2}'),
 ('{"id":"1234","isAvailable":true,"order_id":1}')
```

Now i need to loop inside the each order.data.items array recursively to get both parent & child item id and do a join to Backlog table based on the Backlog.data.id

Final output like to be

[image]

If i didnt explain correctly my needs, please comment i will try to make more verbose as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is in an SQL database, I would recommend you to change your data structure. This looks more like something for NoSQL databases.

Comment: postgres has jsonb support, so went with sql which has nosql support.

Comment: Just because Postgres has a pretty good JSON/NoSQL support, doesn't mean the rules or proper database design should be thrown overboard. Don't use JSON for everything. With a properly normalized model this was as simple as joining two tables. See e.g. here: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: i am junior developer here, i don't really have say for this. I understand you guys are showing me the good way to do but for now i just need solve something like this. (This is system has lakhs of data in this format & been running for almost 2 years now)

Comment: Sure will add now..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated the question

Comment: Your sample data's structure doesn't match the screen shots (mainly the  `id` key is missing for the first elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery (or CTE) and `generate_series()`.

```
select baz from ( select o.data->'items'->generate_series( 0, json_array_length( o.data->'items' ) - 1 )->>'id' as foo, b.data->>'id' as bar, b.data as baz from orders as o, backlog as b ) as t where foo = bar;
```

This returns

```
                         baz                         
-----------------------------------------------------
 {"id": "9012", "order_id": 1, "isAvailable": true}
 {"id": "7890", "order_id": 2, "isAvailable": false}
 {"id": "6543", "order_id": 2, "isAvailable": false}
 {"id": "1234", "order_id": 1, "isAvailable": true}
(4 rows)
```

Deconstructing and understanding my query is left as an exercise.

And read the docs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: It's quite likely that I didn't get all your requirements with parents and children, but I hope this sets you on the right path.